# Find the longest sequence of words where first 2 letters of a word are same as last 2 letters of previous word, sequence ends if word ends with "xx"

Tags: algorithms

This is example of the problem (sequence ends if last 2 letters are "te")

lasag**na** **nato** **top** **op**erati**on** **on**li**ne** **ne**rvo**us** **us**ab**le** **le**vita**te** -> end word ended with "te"

There are around >100K words and the "end" letters are given and you cannot use same word more than once. I tried using going "backward" (find words that end with the begining of the words that end with "te") in a recursive fashion but that takes way to long. What's the most optimal way of finding the longest sequence?

Comment: Make sure you also read the [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/6605).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules define a [**directed graph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory#Directed_graph):

- the words are the vertices of the graph
- the edges of the graph are the directed connections between two words where the first word ends with the two starting letters of the second word, with the exception of pairs where the first word starts with "xx".

Finding the longest sequence of words then means to find the longest path in that graph, which is known as the [Longest Path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). It is known to be NP-hard, so don't expect to find an efficient algorithm. Wikipedia, however, mentions an approximation algorithm, and you could try to apply a discrete optimization algorithm like [Simulated Annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) to find "good" (but nor necessarily optimal) solutions in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: >100k words, 26x26 = 676 connecting letters, so every word connects to 150 words on average. No way on earth to find an optimal solution. I’d read up what I can about approximation algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what are edges in this graph (first letters or 2 first/last letters)?

Comment: @rokob: neither. The edges are the pairs of words where the first word ends with the same two letters as the second one begins with (with the exceptions of those "xx" endings.

Comment: I keep seeing the two letters as nodes and each word as an edge. Any good reason to not do it that way?

Comment: I feel this answer may be overly pessimistic. The map you define doesn't define all directed graphs, just a subset. For example there can't be words x, y, z such that we have xz, yz, xy but not yx. As xy implies x = _____AB, y = AB____CD, xz implies z = AB______, and yz implies z = CD____, so AB = CD and we have yx. Perhaps there is a good algorithm for the subset of directed graphs it defines.

Comment: @candied_orange: the problem statement was *"you cannot use same word more than once."*, not *"you cannot use same two-letter sequence more than once."*, so using the words as vertices directly maps to the longest-path problem.

Comment: @DocBrown I'm sorry but can you visualize it somehow I'm having a hard time understanding how can a word be both the edge and a vertex. Thanks one again.

Comment: @rokob: I did not write the words are edges in the graph. **Pairs** of words form an edge, or if you prefer this, a connection from one word to another one, or a link from one word to another.

Comment: @Countingstuff: perhaps, but I don't see any obvious way to take an advantage from this which makes the problem really simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no chance to find an optimal solution. Too many possibilities.

I’d start with a random last word that has the required end letters, then pick earlier words at random according to the rules, and see how far I get. 100,000 words, so make a few thousand attempts.

I’d then try to find out if there is some heuristics which words can be picked to get longer sequences. Like preferring words with more / fewer connections.

One observation: If say 30 words start with “ab” and 90 words end with “ab” then “ab” can be used as a connection only 30 times, so 60 words can never be used. If you prefer connections that are available often then you’d take this into account.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the context for the question is, but if I was solving this problem, I'd use regular expressions. I'll assume that the words are all separated by a single space character.

The regex to match all word endings followed by a space then the ending repeated again would be `/(\w\w)(?= \1)/`. Try pasting it into [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) to see how it works. Using regex varies per programming language.

As for the word duplication requirement:

> you cannot use same word more than once

you could split the string by each space character to get an array, then deduplicate that.